# I want to subtract the value of only that data for which user is requested for?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

```
db.myc.aggregate([{
    $unwind: "$value"
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$name",
        value1: {
            $first: "$value"
        },
        value2: {
            $last: "$value"
        },
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        Output: { $subtract: ["$value1", 10]}
    }
}]);
```

I want to subtract only that particular value for which user is requested using subtract method

Like if user requested for A+ Then subtraction will be done only in A+ data when Admin accept the request

But don't know how to do this!
So how can I achieve this?

Comment: Please provide sample data and the requested output for it

Comment: Even after the edit it's not clear to me how we can determine which "value" the user is providing and how that maps to the documents. Are you saying that the user will provide a string such as `"A+"` (that represents a grade), these map to the numeric values stored in the `value` array, and that the database should subtract `10` from any entry in that range? If so, what are all of the possible input strings and what numbers do they map to? What is the `$unwind`ing and `$group`ing in the provided pipeline for? If you can better describe what you have and what you want then maybe we can help.

Comment: My Question is simple, look if user request for A+ blood then subtraction should be done in A+ bloodgroup in database when admin approve request for that. I got only method for that so I putted here

Comment: The question may be simple given enough context. Ask the person asking the question, you have that context but we do not. It is your obligation to provide us enough information so that we can assist, see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please at least provide the schema or sample document so that we can better understand the context and background information that you have. What field(s) contain the blood type, what field(s) should have `10` subtracted from, etc